# How extend behaviour of super actor in akka

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-http

I want to implement CRUD operation using akka actor. I am a new in akka so dont know the designing fundamentals of akka actors.

I want to share the behaviours of akka actors in multiple sub actors.

Fir example i want to save and delete student , teacher and other entity.

I have created actor for StudentDao.scala

```
class StudentDao extends Actor with ActorLogging{

 override def Receive = {

    case Add(student) =>
      // Add to database
    case Delete =>
      //Delete from database     
   // Some other cases related to Student entity
  }
}
case object StudentDao{
  case class Add(user : Student)
  case class Delete(id : String)
}
```

Same I have  actor for TeacherDao.scala

```
class TeacherDao extends Actor with ActorLogging{

 override def Receive = {

    case Add(teacher) =>
      // Add to database
    case Delete =>
      //Delete from database      
    // Some other cases related to teacher entity

  }
 }

object TeacherDao{
  case class Add(user : teacher)
  case class Delete(id : String)
}
```

I want to abstract delete method for both dao.
So i have create BaseDao.scala

```
class BaseDao extends Actor with ActorLogging{

  override def Receive = {

    case Delete =>
      //Delete from database   dao.delete
  }
```

how can i abstract using base actor.

Answer (score 1):

[`orElse`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/actors.html#extending-actors-using-partialfunction-chaining) is the way to extend actor behaviors, because an actor's `Receive` is simply an alias for `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`. Below is a concrete illustration with your use case.

First, define the base behavior in a trait that must be mixed in with an actor. To avoid duplication, move the `Delete` case class into this trait's companion object.

```
trait BaseDao { this: Actor with ActorLogging =>
  import BaseDao._

  def baseBehavior: Receive = {
    case Delete(id) =>
      log.info(s"Deleting $id from db")
      // delete from db
  }
}

object BaseDao {
  case class Delete(id: String)
}
```

Then, mix in the above trait into your other actors and chain the behaviors with `orElse`. Note that I created dummy `Student` and `Teacher` case classes so that this code would compile. `StudentDao`:

```
class StudentDao extends Actor with ActorLogging with BaseDao {
  import StudentDao._

  def studentBehavior: Receive = {
    case Add(student) =>
      log.info(s"Adding student: $student")
    // some other cases related to Student
  }

  def receive = studentBehavior orElse baseBehavior
}

object StudentDao {
  case class Add(user: Student)
}
case class Student(name: String)
```

And `TeacherDao`:

```
class TeacherDao extends Actor with ActorLogging with BaseDao {
  import TeacherDao._

  def teacherBehavior: Receive = {
    case Add(teacher) =>
      log.info(s"Adding teacher: $teacher")
    // some other cases related to Teacher
  }

  def receive = teacherBehavior orElse baseBehavior
}

object TeacherDao {
  case class Add(user: Teacher)
}
case class Teacher(name: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trait for the base actor, with a common receive function `orElse` another one that has to be implemented in sub actors:

```
trait BaseActor extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = commonReceive orElse handleReceive

  def commonReceive: Receive = {
    case CommonMessage => // do something
  }

  def handleReceive: Receive
}
```

And then your sub actors only have to implement handleReceive:

```
class SubActor extends BaseActor {

  override def handleReceive: Receive = {
    case SpecificMessage => // do something
  }
}
```